# django-sphinx-db: raw sql queries, join with msql tables?

Tags: django, sphinx, django-sphinx

I am thinking of using django-sphinx-db  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sphinx-db

Before I install it, just thought I would check:

Is it possible to join the special sphinx tables with the regular mysql tables? Can I do this  using raw queries?

Any other thoughts on django-sphinx-db? Any reason I should not use it?

I plan to index some text content in sphinx, but will have the matching images in a mysql table. So I would need to do a join of the content table and the image table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to join the special sphinx tables with the regular mysql tables?

No.

`SphinxQL` (and hence `django-sphinx-db`) is a seperate 'server'. So you connect to mysql to run mysql queries, and searchd to make sphinxql queries. They are on seperate physical servers with seperate connections.

With `django-sphinx-db` you would use it to manage a connection, to the SphinxSearch instance, and your favorite system for accessing mysql server.

You run the sphinx query, then fetch documents from mysql. Performing the 'join' in **application** code.

--

For joining need to use SphinxSE. Then you just use normal connections to mysql server, to run queries (the mysql server, via SphinxSE internally runs that actual sphinx query) 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxse

In theroy can also use the FEDERATED mysql engine, to similar effect to SphinxSE. Just using FEDERATED to proxy though to a sphinxQL backend. But it will probably be tricky to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks, this is as I suspected. Do you know if there is there a speed difference, running it via django-sphinx-db or SphinxSE? Maybe there is some connection overhead each time a query os run or...? I'm just as concerned about insert speed as search speed.

Comment: ITs an apples-to-oranges comparsion. They are two totally different technologies/approaches to the problem. Which to use is not a performance question.